# JQUERY fails to set parameter when currentRow.next().next() is not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services, jquery-ui

I have a jquery save function like this -

```
    $(".SaveBtn").click(function () {
        if ($("#Form1").valid()) {
            var rowData = $("#TestTable").getRowData($(this).data("rowid"));
            var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
            var postData = {
                testID: rowData.testID,
                testNotes: currentRow.next().find(".NotesEntry").val(),
                isActive: currentRow.next().next().find(".CheckEntry") == null ? "false" : currentRow.next().next().find(".CheckEntry").prop("checked"),
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Services/test.asmx/UpdateTestRowData",
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d != null) {
                        $("#TestTable").setGridParam({ postData: { myID: $('#hfmyID').val() }, datatype: 'json' }).trigger("reloadGrid");
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The problem is with this line -

```
isActive: currentRow.next().next() == null ? "false" : currentRow.next().next().find(".CheckEntry").prop("checked"),
                    };
```

When currentRow.next().next() is not available, the isActive is not set as "false" and is even not in the request body to web service.

Currently the request body is {"testID":"e9c966ace446-4f73-9ba0-26e686b2a308","testNotes":"TEST"}

I expect it to be -
{"testID":"e9c966ace446-4f73-9ba0-26e686b2a308","testNotes":"TEST", "isActive":"false"}

Why the "isActive" parameter is missed and how to make it available when currentRow.next().next() is not available?

Thanks

Comment: jQuery DOM selection/traversing will never return `null`.

Comment: can you show the relevant html?

Comment: Thanks @Deuterium.  I answered my question with html there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding the else part in the following statement -

```
                    if (data.d.IsActived) {
                        output += "<td colspan='6' align=\"left\"><input type='checkbox' id='cbActive" + rowId + " checked" + " name='cbManualDeactive" + rowId + "' class='CheckEntry CheckEntry' data-registrationid='" + data.d.ID + "' data-rowid='" + rowId + "'/></td>";
                    }
                    else {
                        output += "<td style=\"display:none;\"><input type='checkbox' id='cbActive" + rowId  + " name='cbActive" + rowId + "' class='CheckEntry CheckEntry' data-registrationid='" + data.d.ID + "' data-rowid='" + rowId + "'/></td>";
                    }
```

Thanks